# Yii2 How to get all values from column (DB)

Tags: php, database, yii, yii2

I've been sitting for hours trying to find how to get values from table's `iab_categories` column `category_name`. I've found only the way to echo all table names:

```
$connection = Yii::app()->db;//get connection
$dbSchema = $connection->schema;
//or $connection->getSchema();
$tableNames = $dbSchema->getTableNames();//returns array of tbl schema's
var_export($tableNames);
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [query builder](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-query-builder) to do that:

```php
$categories = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select(['category_name'])
    ->from('iab_categories')
    ->column();
```

The `select()` method sets what columns should be included in result.
The `from()` method sets what table should be queried.
And the `column()` method executes the query and return first column from result set as array.

EDIT: now, I've realized that even though you've mentioned Yii 2 in title the code you've included in question looks more like Yii 1.x.
So there is [query builder](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder) version for Yii 1.x:

```php
$categories = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('category_name')
    ->from('iab_categories')
    ->queryColumn();
```